# MSSQL Return 2 Columns from diffrent tables

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to return the top 10 rows from two separate columns from two tables using a SELECT query to allow the resultant dataset to be used in a graph. I tried to use a JOIN command however I don't have two similar columns in each table to allow me to join them. 
I.ve been trying the following code but this returns the first arguments list against the first line of the second argument and so on. I then end up with 100 rows in my data set !

```
    SELECT x.trend1_ndx, y.sine2
    FROM (SELECT TOP 10 trend1_ndx FROM trend1) as x, (SELECT TOP 10
    sine2 FROM newgraph ) as y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly inferred, you need an identical value in both datasets to be able to join them 1-by-1. `ROW_NUMBER` to the rescue! This query adds a value of 1 - 10 for each record in the subselects, then uses this column in the join:

```
SELECT x.trend1_ndx, y.sine2
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 10 trend1_ndx, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY trend1_ndx) as N
     FROM trend1) as x 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT TOP 10 sine2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sine2) as N
     FROM newgraph) as y 
ON x.N = y.N
```

Now, you might need to change the ordering to something else, to make sure that the x-values get paired up with the correct y-values (this is something you would have to take care of regardless, as the order of data returned using a `SELECT` statement is never guaranteed, when you don't specify an `ORDER BY` clause.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, It worked first time. I've been going round in circles for hours trying to solve this.